# Jade escaping issue?

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm having a problem with my website. Everything is working locally but when I deploy on Heroku, there are multiple HTML errors (view console logs).

Why the fonts loads as a 302 instead of 200?

What's the problem? Thanks.

[Heroku link](https://mlg-2017.herokuapp.com)

Comment: Don't link to your site that might be busted, broken, or simply dead in the future. **Put the code in the body of your question**.

Comment: Haven't used Heroku before but clicking your jQuery link in your source redirects to the index, is that normal behaviour? Can you try a CDN link instead of local and see if that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code is largely invalid.

**1. You should provide a document type declaration**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**2. You should use quotes properly (`''` and `""`)**

This is incorrect:

```
<header style="background-image:url("http://68.media.tumblr.com/cf2b0eeba721d280c9ad974d62d4625d/tumblr_inline_oi6jo8eXpU1svyka8_540.jpg")" class="image">
```

Solution:

```
<header style="background-image:url('http://68.media.tumblr.com/cf2b0eeba721d280c9ad974d62d4625d/tumblr_inline_oi6jo8eXpU1svyka8_540.jpg')" class="image">
```

**3. You should fix typos (`alertnate` !== `alternate`)**

This is incorrect:

```
<link rel="alertnate" hreflang="en" href="https://mlg-2017.herokuapp.com"/>
```

Solution:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://mlg-2017.herokuapp.com">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why I'm having a 302 on my custom fonts?